# Hadoop copyMerge not working properly: scala

Tags: scala, hadoop

I'm trying to combine 3 files present in HDFS through scala. All the 3 files are present in the HDFS location `srcPath` as mentioned in the code below.

Created a function as below:

```
def mergeFiles(conf: Configuration, fs: FileSystem, srcPath: Path, dstPath: String, finalFileName: String): Unit {
val localfs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf)
val status = fs.listStatus(srcPath)

status.foreach(x =>
FileUtil.copyMerge(fs, x.getPath, localfs, new Path(dstPath.toString), false, conf, null)
}
```

I tried executing this, no result, no error, also no file gets created even.
I verified that I'm passing all the arguments properly.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `copyMerge` is a directory, not an individual file.
This should work:

`FileUtil.copyMerge(fs, srcPath, localfs, new Path(dstPath.toString), false, conf, null)`

Usually reading the source code is the best way to debug such issues.

Comment: Thanks @simpadjo. Yes, that makes sense; I was trying to achieve a specific order of file appends. copyMerge will combine all the files one by one the way it picks from the folder. What if I wanted in a specific order?

Comment: The most simple way is copying implementation of `copyMerge` and replacing `contents` with what you want. There is no magic inside, you'll get ~10 lines of boring scala code,

Comment: You're right. That's the best way to go. I'll implement it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

FileUtil#copyMerge method has been removed. See details for the major change:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12967

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11392

You can use getmerge

Usage: hadoop fs -getmerge [-nl]

Comment: in version in Hadoop 3.0